# Accessing fabric state attributes from getPrivateStateByRange query

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am having the following problem. I am trying to write a chaincode function which queries my private data store and returns a subset of the states based on some attribute checks. Lets take the fabcar example and assume that the car states are private in my collection. I would like to query all cars that satisfy certain conditions based on their attributes. So I thought I can loop through the states similarly like in the queryAllCars function and then access the fields after I parsed it. Following is my approach for a different use case. This always throws "cannot read property color of undefined". I don't understand how that can be undefined. Without the propertycheck there is a record with the according properties (color, make, model...) in JSON format returned.

```
async queryAllPrivateCarsWithSomeConditions(ctx) {
        const startKey = 'CAR0';
        const endKey = 'CAR999';

        const range = await ctx.stub.getPrivateDataByRange(startKey, endKey);

        const allResults = [];
        while (true) {
            const res = await range.iterator.next();

            if (res.value && res.value.value.toString()) {
                console.log(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));

                const Key = res.value.key;
                let car;
                let color;
                try {
                    car = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));
                    color = CarRecord.color;
                    if(Color == "x"){
                      //whatever
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    Record = res.value.value.toString('utf8');
                }
                allResults.push({ Key, Record });
            }
            if (res.done) {
                console.log('end of data');
                await range.iterator.close();
                console.info(allResults);
                return JSON.stringify(allResults);
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems to be possible to access the properties in the case of a single state query as in the example changeCarOwner where I can access the object prop color after parsing.

`code`

```
async changeCarOwner(ctx, carNumber, newOwner) {
        console.info('============= START : changeCarOwner ===========');

        const carAsBytes = await ctx.stub.getState(carNumber); // get the car from chaincode state
        if (!carAsBytes || carAsBytes.length === 0) {
            throw new Error(`${carNumber} does not exist`);
        }
        const car = JSON.parse(carAsBytes.toString());
        car.owner = newOwner;

        await ctx.stub.putState(carNumber, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(car)));
        console.info('============= END : changeCarOwner ===========');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `CarRecord` is indeed undefined in your code. Try changing `color = CarRecord.color;` to `color = car.color;`.
Note that `car`, not `CarRecord` is initialised one line earlier: `car = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));`.